# How can I get the width and height of a text that was Image.Draw-drawn on a picture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0MXd.jpg)There are already a few questions, that sound quite similar to this one on stackoverflow, but their focuses are a little bit different from what I want to know.

I pasted a text on an image using ImageDraw from the Python Image Library. My question now is: Is there a way to find out the width and height of the text as a whole? For myself imagine the text to have kind of a rectangular frame. I want to get the measurements of this text-field. Can my text1 be treated like an image and can I get its size by typing in something like "width, height = text1.size"?

I have already tried to get the width, by using a ImageDraw.getwidth command, as proposed in other questions, but those solutions sadly didn't work for me.

What I want to achieve in particular is to be able to calculate, where the next text-field can be placed without overlaying the current text.

Thanks in advance for your support!

In the attached picture you can see the two ImageDraw-drawed texts, named "text" and "xyz". I want xyz to fit behind "test", even if "test" would include more letters. Therefor I need to know the width of "test".

Comment: your image is a numpy array, you can slice it until you get your `pasted text` and it's shape is the `width` and `height`

Comment: thanks, that sounds good, but also a little complicated for a python newbie ^^. How exactly can this be done? Don't I have to convert it to a NumPy array and use several commands to get the width then? Isn't there maybe an easier solution?

Comment: show an example image and I'll post the code

Comment: I added a link to the image and some details to the descripton.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write the same text with the same font of the same size in white on a separate canvas (black background) and then get the trimmed *"bounding box"* like this which is the size:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL  import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

# Create a blank canvas
canvas = Image.new('RGB', (100,100))

# Get a drawing context
fontsize=28
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
monospace = ImageFont.truetype("/Library/Fonts/Andale Mono.ttf",fontsize)

text = "Hello"
white = (255,255,255)
draw.text((10, 10), text, font=monospace, fill=white)

# Find bounding box
bbox = canvas.getbbox()

# Debug
print(bbox)
```

**Output**

```
(12, 17, 93, 36)
```

That means the text is (93-12) = 81 pixels wide and (36-17) = 19 pixels tall.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

using opencv or matplotlib to read your image

`img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/home/ksooklall/q0MXd.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)`

find the image location

`text1 = img[950:, 50:250]`

```
print(text1.shape)
(50, 200, 3)
```

[image]