# Writing into a specific field with PIL Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

There is an image that I have written on using the Python PIL library. I am using x and y of the upper left corner when writing a text and this is working fine.

Here is my code:

```
image = Image.open('Test.png')
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
font = ImageFont.truetype("Dharma.otf", 45)
color1 = 'rgb(0,0,0)'
text = "Test Text"
draw.text((261, 149), text, fill=color1, font=font)
```

But now, i need to different thing.
I have to print the text in the middle by giving x, y of the upper left corner and x, y of the lower right corner.

Sample image;

[image]

I can do it according to the length of the post using if, but this is difficult.
Can I center this with PIL by entering 2 x and y?

Comment: Do you mean you want the text to automatically get larger and smaller according to the size of the box? Or do you mean you know the font-size and you are just having trouble with the positioning? If you mean the later see here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887152/2836621 Then your top-left `x` position would be half of (image width - text width) and the top-left `y` position would be half of (image height - text height).

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to explain by giving an example. Actually, there is an image (1280x720) .And there is a box in this picture. Top left corner x, y = (445, 140) and bottom right corner x, y = (720, 183). So, I want to write text centered in a box inside an image.

Comment: Ok, do you know the font size you want to use?

Comment: Yes, the font is specific. Its 45. @MarkSetchell

Comment: Ok, do exactly what it says in the answer I linked to above and get the size of the box that contains the text you want to draw. Can you do that bit?

Comment: @MarkSetchell i will try it today..

Comment: @MarkSetchell I guess i didn't get it because I couldn't.