# PIL put text in the center of pixel

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, python-imaging-library, pixel

How do I put text in the center of a **pixel** using Pillow library?

```
draw.text((227, 15), 'Foo', (0, 0, 0) ,font=font)
```

The thing that I get right now is kinda like this (Red point is the pixel):

[image]

What I want is (again red point is the pixel):

[image]

I hope this explains well.
How do I achieve my target?

**Note that:**
The question isn't about putting the text in the middle of a **picture**, its about putting it in the center of a **pixel**.

Comment: The question isn't about putting the text in the middle of a picture, its about putting it in the center of a pixel. Please reopen

Comment: What's the difference between the middle and the center?

Comment: @pppery You are right. There is no difference between the center and the middle. But do you know if there is a difference between *center of an image* and *center of a pixel*?? Pixel can be a point anywhere in the image, whereas center of an image is always going to be center of image. Read again the question.

Comment: It's the same as here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/59887152/2836621 You draw your letter on a separate, blank canvas and trim it to its bounding box. Then you average the x coordinates and the y coordinates to get the centre pixel.

Answer (score -1):

Some steps to paste text on center of image.

1. create one bigger image which can fit all text.

```py
im = Image.new(...)
```

2. draw text on it

```py
draw.text(...)
```

3. check the size of text

```py
box = im.getbbox()
```

4. Then you can calculate where you should draw you text on your image.